# Sphinx and reStructuredText: multiple code highlighting in a single block

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am new to Sphinx. I am writing some documentation for embedded UDFs that requires a code block to contain 2 languages (e.g. SQL and python). At present I can only see how to have a single highlight language in a block.

Is it possible to "switch" languages within a block? Below is an example of reStructuredText that results in 3 code block that I want to merge into one.
Simply removing the second and third "::" doesn't work.

```
.. highlight:: sql
::

    SELECT * FROM
    EXTERNAL SCRIPT(

.. highlight:: R
::

    #Some R markup
    MEANS = matrix(runif(nclust*ndim)*sqrt(nclust)*sep, nrow = nclust)
    VARS = matrix(runif(nclust)*ndim, nrow = nclust)
    ps = 1:nclust
    ps = ps/sum(ps)

.. highlight:: sql
::

    )
    FROM myshema.mySQLtable
```

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure that this cannot be done by default, and your solution of using separate 'highlight' blocks is the standard procedure to show multiple languages.

I believe that this is for the best anyway as mixing code in one block is usually a bad idea as it can confuse readers.

Also, when converting reStructuredText into HTML for example, a style sheet is used to make everything look pretty, and a default style sheet is included. If you do some research, I'm sure you could edit that style sheet or make your own, perhaps making the 'border' invisible and the 'margin-bottom' zero pixels for 'highlight' blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this extension to have different languages in tabs:

https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/src/c30b46a0a1b5c21ec9977e6abc598d0654316ac2/examplecode/?at=default

Comment: This looks interesting, but you should add some more content to the answer. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.